# Later added nodes are not attached to jQuery UI functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm currently designing a single page application and wanted to make use of jQuery UI.
Unfortunately jQuery UI does not attach its functionality to dynamically added elements.
So inserting a jQuery UI button (having all necessary classes) after loading the page erases all functionalities (e.g. change color on hover).
jQuery's deprecated live()-method should be able to avoid that but obviously it isn't used by jQuery UI.

I hope you have an idea! :)

Thanks a lot!

Leo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the event in the code that adds the new element. See this fiddle for an example.

http://jsfiddle.net/uHEre/3/

Also, as noted in the fiddle comments, `.on()` is the new `.live()`. See http://api.jquery.com/on/